# Logstash Geoip does not output coordinates as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, geoip, kibana

I'm trying to set long and lat for the Kibana Bettermap using Geoip. I'm using Logstash 1.4.2 and Elasticsearch 1.1.1 and the following is my configuration file:

```
input
{
   stdin { }
}

filter
{
   geoip
   {
     source => "ip"
   }
}

output
{
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

When I send the following example ip address:

```
"ip":"00.00.00.00"
```

The result is as follows:

```
{
      "message" => "\"ip\":\"00.000.00.00\"",
      "@version" => "1",
      "@timestamp" => "2014-10-20T22:23:12.334Z",
}
```

As you can see, no geoip coordinates, and nothing on my Kibana Bettermap. What can I do to get this Bettermap to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't parsing the message... Either add `codec => json` to your `stdin` and send in `{"ip":"8.8.8.8"}` or use a `grok` filter to parse your input:

```
grok { match => ['message', '%{IP:ip}' ] }
```